# celery: Dispatching lots of jobs at once

Tags: python, celery

currently, I have about ~5000 jobs that i have dispatch and im dispatching in a loop:

```
for i, job in enumerate(Jobs):
    res = process_job.apply_async(args=[job], queue='job_queue')
```

it took about 18 seconds to complete the loop

i've tried sending them all as a group() call but it seems to be slow as well.

any suggestion on how to dispatch multiple jobs fast?

ALSO, i've tried to parallelize dispatch via multiprocessing but the overhead of the thread/process seems to negate the benefit as well

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on how `Jobs` is retrieved, but we handle this using a dispatcher task and then we can just call the dispatcher task.

```
@task
def process_job(job):
    # do stuff for this job

@task
def dispatcher():
    for job in Jobs:
        process_job.apply_async(args=[job], queue='job_queue')
```

Comment: can you elaborate what benefit you would have that by dispatching the logic for dispatching jobs vs. not dispatching that?

Comment: and how does your Jobs get retrieved?

Comment: The benefit is the dispatching is handled asynchronously so the code can continue whilst the jobs are being  dispatched in one of your workers. Jobs (in our case) are retrieved from a database query in the dispatcher task

Comment: Of course if your issue is that 18 seconds is too long in general because of some other requirement in your app, then this won't help you

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try [celery-dispatcher](https://github.com/gsfish/celery-dispatcher), which use an independent thread to dispatch tasks.

you can yield subtasks in the main task and handle each result within another function:

```
def handle_result(root_id, task_id, retval, **kwargs):
    print(retval)

@shared_task
def sqrt(i):
    return i * i

@dispatch(receiver=handle_result)
@shared_task
def calc():
    for i in range(10):
        yield sqrt, (i,)
```